# No JSON Data being returned

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

I have this php GET function

```
function genre_get($genre) {

$this->load->database();
    $sql = 'SELECT games.id, games.title, games.developer, reviews.NoReviews ';
    $sql .= 'FROM games INNER JOIN ';
$sql .= '(SELECT ean, COUNT(*) as NoReviews ';
$sql .= 'FROM reviews GROUP BY ean) reviews ';
$sql .= 'ON games.ean = reviews.ean ';
$sql .= 'WHERE games.genre= "'.$genre.'";';
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    $data = $query->result();
$info->games=$data;
$this->response($data, 200);
 }
```

And although there are no errors its not outputting any JSON data. Using the sql syntax in the mysql command prompt it does generate a table however using this on the apigee console returns nothing.

I know the above SQL Does work using MYSQL and it does return a table

```
 function genre_get($genre) {
     $this->load->database();
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM games ';
        $sql .= 'WHERE genre = "'.$genre.'";';
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        $data = $query->result();
    $info->games=$data;
        $this->response($data, 200);
     }
```

I used this function previously and it worked and got the data required

Comment: I think you'll need to post more data from the request and response.  Do you have a value in `$data` before `$this->response` sends out the data?

Comment: Does it work when `$genre` is `foo' or 1=1; --`? Beware of SQL injection.

Comment: i dont understand what you mean

Comment: He means that a malicious user could send this data to the server though $gender : x"; DROP TABLE GAMES; -- . What this does is injecting malicious statement () in your query . WHERE genre = "'.$genre.'"; will become : WHERE genre = "x"; DROP TABLE GAMES; --";

Comment: You can't just take a MySQL result object, throw the resource handle at a HTTP library and expect a magical transformation to JSON...

Comment: @GeoC.: Probably not. Most DB APIs disable multi-statement queries for this very reason. There are better examples you can pick.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Maybe the underlieing library is using multi_query , i was just trying to explain to him how sql injection works and to give him a harmfull example . or 1=1; -- is too abstract and might never actually harm the system (i'm saying this just to underline the same logic that you are hanging on regarding my example, given the context) .

Answer (score 0):

The result must be encoded with JSON FORMAT. You can use de json_encode function.

Example:
$this->response(json_encode($data), 200);

Reference:  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your JSON encoder, but perhaps your SQL query needs an alias for result columns, e.g.

```
SELECT games.id AS id, games.title AS title, games.developer AS developer, reviews.NoReviews AS NoReviews
```